# Prove using complex numbers $e^{(x+y)} = e^x e^y$ for all $x,y$ complex.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

Title pretty much says it all, but I have a couple of additional questions.
1) Is it even possible?

2) If it is, then where do we start? Like what is the definition of $e$? Is it possible to do this without defining $e$ as the solution to $f'(x) = f(x)$, or as the limit $n\to\infty$ of $(1+1/n)^n$?

3) If $x,y$ were real, is it possible to prove the claim without using complex numbers or real analysis?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding (3), $e$ is pretty much defined based on analysis so you'll probably need to use it, regardless of which definition you pick

Comment: You can begin with the Taylor series definition of $e^x$ and prove all of it's properties from there. It doesn't make much sense to discuss $e$ outside of analysis given its definitively analytic nature.

Comment: @GuidoA It's as much defined based on analysis as any other real number. No reason why not to just prove that $r^{x+y} = r^xr^y$ for any $r\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I mean, I see your point but then again, $e$ is defined by integrals, differential equations, series or a _very specific_ limit. If I recall correctly, you can define the reals as a completion of the rationals without any of that machinery. So in a sense, $e$ "requires more analysis" than just any random number. 

Edit: also, having characterizations of $e$ makes the proof a lot easier, and from there you can generalize it to $\mathbb{R}$. The other way around is potentially harder.

Comment: When you say “complex numbers,” are you allowing $\operatorname{cis}\theta=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$? Also, there isn’t much of a basic definition as$$e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n$$

Comment: Depends on what your definition of $e^x$ is for complex $x$.

Comment: @Crescendo Yes, but not e^iQ = cis Q. Basically, is there a way to prove e^x+y = e^x e^y while 'treating' e as any real number as Michael Lee points out?

Answer (score 1):

For complex numbers I would start with $\displaystyle \exp(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n$.

Then use the Cauchy product to have $$\displaystyle \exp(z)\exp(w)=\left(\sum_{ n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n\right)\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}w^k \right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}z^pw^{n-p}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(z+w)^n=\exp(z+w).$$